# Display int values inputted by a user on the line with spaces

Tags: java, string

I want my program to input int values from the user on the same line (e.g. 12345), and display the output with spaces between the int values(1   2   3     4    5). Please help.

```
{
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
     int num = input.nextInt();
     String van = toString(num);
     System.out.println("The Numbers are: " + van);
 }
```

Comment: Can the numbers ever be greater than 9?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, for example:

### Solution 1

You can use for example [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) from Java8+, like so :

```
String van = String.valueOf(num);
System.out.println(String.join(" ", van.split("")));
```

Outputs

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

### Solution 2

You can use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) like this :

```
System.out.println(van.replaceAll(".", "$ ").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < van.length(); i++)
    System.out.print(van.charAt(i) + " ");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be following

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    String value = String.valueOf(num);
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        newString = newString + value.charAt(i) + " ";
    }
    System.out.println("newString=>" + newString.trim());
```